# Azure Python Function Import Workaround

Tags: python, azure-function-app

Apologies if this has been asked before; it seems to be a bit of a recurring theme, but I'm keen to learn whether there is a better way to handle this situation than I am currently using.

I am trying to identify the cleanest way to handle importing modules in my Azure Python function. Currently this is what I have to do:

```
import logging
import sys
import pathlib
import os

parent = str(pathlib.Path(__file__).parent) + '\.venv\Lib\site-packages'
sys.path.append(parent)
import azure.functions as func
```

If I don't then I get the dreaded import error for azure.functions module.

I have taken to putting my .venv INSIDE the function dir then making sure that .venv is added to the .funcignore so it does not get uploaded.

My project structure looks like this:
[image: folder structure]

So the parent var is getting me up to the TimerTrigger1 then I append the .venv\Lib\site-packages then add that to the path so that the import of azure.functions does not fail.

My question: Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid you should do append to let Python know where your modules reside so it can correctly import them into your scripts for use.

```
import sys, os.path
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname( __file__ ), 'yourenv/Lib/site-packages')))
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I don't feel so bad about how I'm setting things up. Wish there were a 'cleaner' way.